# Win32 code example - punch holes into file to deallocate blocks and make it a "sparse file"?

Tags: winapi, sparse-file

Linux has fallocate(fd, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE|FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE, ...)
to punch a hole into a file, i.e. deallocate the blocks given and make
the file a "sparse file".

Does anyone have a Win32 ISO C code example (Microsoft docs do not have EXAMPLES!) to do the same with the Win32 API, e.g. code which demonstrates how to punch two holes into a file, say, at positions 34000...51000 and 71000...91000?

Comment: Have you read the [Sparse Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/sparse-files) documentation on MSDN yet? Per [Sparse File Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/sparse-file-operations): "*the application must explicitly declare a file as sparse, using the FSCTL_SET_SPARSE control code. After an application has set a file to be sparse, the application can use the FSCTL_SET_ZERO_DATA control code to set a region of the file to zero.*"